# Oracle SQL pull in records after second 0 in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I edit my query to only pull in records after the SECOND most recent `0` value in the "Within_100" field

my query:

```
SELECT id,
       unixdatetime,
       ordernumber,
       date_time,
       next_unixdatetime,
       next_unixdatetime - unixdatetime AS diff,
       CASE cls
       WHEN 'WITHIN_100' THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END AS within_100
from   (
  select distinct 
         ID,
         UnixDateTime,
         OrderNumber,
         TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + UnixDateTime * INTERVAL '1' SECOND
           AS Date_Time
  from   DB
  where  TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + UnixDateTime * INTERVAL '1' SECOND
           > SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '2' DAY
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY unixdatetime
  MEASURES
    NEXT(unixdatetime) AS next_unixdatetime,
    classifier() AS cls
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (within_100* any_row)
  DEFINE
    within_100 AS NEXT(unixdatetime) < unixdatetime + 100
) m
```

output result:

| ID | UNIXDATETIME | ORDERNUMBER | DATE_TIME | NEXT_UNIXDATETIME | DIFF | WITHIN_100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1662615688 | 100 | 2022-09-08 05:41:28 | 1662615752 | 64 | 1 |
| 2 | 1662615752 | 100 | 2022-09-08 05:42:32 | 1662615765 | 13 | 1 |
| 3 | 1662615765 | 100 | 2022-09-08 05:42:45 | 1662615859 | 94 | 1 |
| 4 | 1662615859 | 100 | 2022-09-08 05:44:19 | 1662615987 | 128 | 0 |
| 5 | 1662615987 | 100 | 2022-09-08 05:46:27 | 1662616031 | 44 | 1 |
| 6 | 1662616031 | 100 | 2022-09-08 05:47:11 | null | null | 0 |

so i would only want to pull in ID records 5 & 6
thank you

Comment: It would be better to edit and improve [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73649619/266304) rather than deleting and reposting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `$` to the pattern to only match the most recent pattern and not a global match:

```sql
SELECT id,
       unixdatetime,
       ordernumber,
       date_time,
       next_unixdatetime,
       next_unixdatetime - unixdatetime AS diff,
       CASE cls
       WHEN 'WITHIN_100' THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END AS within_100
from   (
  select distinct 
         ID,
         UnixDateTime,
         OrderNumber,
         TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + UnixDateTime * INTERVAL '1' SECOND
           AS Date_Time
  from   DB
  where  TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + UnixDateTime * INTERVAL '1' SECOND
           > SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '2' DAY
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY unixdatetime
  MEASURES
    NEXT(unixdatetime) AS next_unixdatetime,
    classifier() AS cls
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (within_100* any_row $)
  DEFINE
    within_100 AS NEXT(unixdatetime) < unixdatetime + 100
) m
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE db (ID, UnixDateTime, OrderNumber) AS
SELECT 1, 1662615688, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1662615752, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1662615765, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1662615859, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 1662615987, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 1662616031, 100 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | UNIXDATETIME | ORDERNUMBER | DATE_TIME | NEXT_UNIXDATETIME | DIFF | WITHIN_100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1662615987 | 100 | 2022-09-08 05:46:27.000000000 UTC | 1662616031 | 44 | 1 |
| 6 | 1662616031 | 100 | 2022-09-08 05:47:11.000000000 UTC | *null* | *null* | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pSvVrB33)